# Installation of beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation

I am using `Python 2.7.13`

I have used the command prompt to install beautifulsoup : `easy_install beautifulsoup4`
I got messages with a `best match', 'downloading ..... et`c  and finally an `error:None`.

However when running a script which says

`from BeautifulSoup import *`

I got the error message

```
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

1. does the `error: None` mean it has installed properly
2. what does it actually do when you install `beautifulsoup`, is it there forever? Do you need to install it each time you use Python? Where does it install it to i.e. where should I check to see if its actually there ?

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`  also gives the same answer

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

You can install Beautiful Soup with PIP(python package index)

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```